# Может ли одушевленное существительное отвечать на вопрос "что?"

Tags: выбор-слов, общие-вопросы, одушевленность

Вопрос возник в контексте создания вопросов для викторин.

Будут ли корректны такие вопросы с ответами:

- Что изображено на гербе Москвы? Георгий Победоносец с драконом.
- Чем расплачиваются селениты за товары и услуги в произведении Сирано
  де Бержерака? Один из неверных вариантов "Детьми"
- Что такое "зеница ока"? Один из неверных вариантов "Близкий человек"
- Что получает команда знатоков "Что? Где? Когда?" при правильном
  досрочном ответе? Один из неверных вариантов "Дополнительного
  игрока".

Некоторые участники требует расширения формулировки таких вопросов в виде "что или кто", "что или кого", "чем или кем" и так далее. Обоснованно ли такое требование или в подобной постановке вопроса вопросительное слово "что" корректно?
Если возможно, подскажите правило, которым это определяется.

Comment: На гербе Москвы изображено... В произведении Сирано де Бержерака селениты за товары расплачиваются... Зеница ока — это... При правильном досрочном ответе команда знатоков получает...

Comment: Хотелось бы все же использовать полноценные предложения

Comment: Eka, мне очень понравился вопрос. Хотелось бы видеть Вас в качестве постоянного участника этого сайта.

Answer (score 4):

Ох...
Думаю, что все вопросы в исходном виде корректны.

Не хочу я спорить с Людмилой по поводу разбора каждого примера, но мне кажется вопрос этот не совсем по русскому языку. Тут контекст важнее всего. Что за Олимпиада такая, как там принято трактовать подобные вопросы? И, насколько понимаю, речь идет о выработке именно единого подхода. Если разные вопросы будут в этой части иметь разную формулировку, то это вызовет как минимум желание участников найти закономерность - и получить незаконную подсказку.

Но перво-наперво, хотелось бы услышать аргументацию ваших оппонентов. Почему они так ставят вопрос? Если это опять же борьбе с незапланированной организаторами подсказкой" *скажем, второй вопрос (чем расплачивались) по мнению кого-то из участников своей формулировкой исключает приведенный ответ (детьми)*, то такое мнение имет смысл обсуждать. А если это просто влияние английского (там сама постановка имеет смысл в силу особенностей грамматики), то гнать этих авторов в шею.

Что же до русского языка, то, как верно уже было сказано, вопрос "что" предполагает любой вариант ответа, если заранее одушевленность не предполагается.

***Что просил князь у Хас-Булата взамен богатства? Жену, коня, раба, сына***
***Ну неужели же здесь кто-то потребует "кого?"?!***

Думаю, этого достаточно. Максимум, что можно сделать - оговорить в правилах, что "что (чего, чем)" не означает обязательную неодушевленность ответа.

*Если очень надо, могу развить в другой раз, но не хочется этот ответ перегружать лишними сведениями.*

Comment: Автор просил ссылки на правило, вот и пыталась привязать к правилам русского языка, вернее к семантике.

Comment: В ходе игры-викторины надо просто выбирать один правильный вариант ответа из четырех. Скорее у нас делаются попытки сделать вопросы "правильнее". Примеры вопросов и жалоб на них: В:Что изображается на тханке? Ж: "Что или кто ...?" Иерархи - кто. В: Что из перечисленного не имеет отношения к фауне? Ж:Линь, лань и лунь - ЭТО КТО, поскольку одушевлённые; В: Что такое мангостан? Ж: Каким образом птица и хищный зверёк могут отвечать на вопрос Что такое?, если они одушевлённые? И так далее. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Eka  Судя по всему, вы не очень поняли мой ответ. Речь не о том, принцип игры понятен изначально. Но я считаю, что здесь просто нет смысла апеллировать к какому-то правилу. Тут больше ваше внутреннее соглашение должно работать. Есоь уточнение (ваш термин) может рассматриваться как наводящая информация, то таклй информации в вопросе не должно быть. Вот это единственное что имеет смысл обсуждать. Всё остальное - за уши притянуто. Из этого надо исходить..

Comment: @Людмила Я вам каждый раз задаю вопрос в лоб - и каждый раз вы от него уходите. Но попробую ещё раз. В выдуманном мной примере (*Что просил князь у Хас-Булата взамен богатства? Жену, коня, раба, сына*) вы будете рассматривать хотя бы гипотетически вариант ***"кого?"***. Я -- нет и никогда. Это, вашим языком выражаясь, не по-русски (Нечто подобное вы мне сказали про вопрос "свернулся чем?" - "калачиком"). Если вы будете настаивать на варианте, *"кого попросил князь...?"*, то мы никогда не поймем друг друга.

Comment: А если не будете, то все ваши благие намерения навести какой-то порядок в одушевленности вопроса становятся иллюзорными. Вот это причина того, почему я не стал с вами спорить напрямую.

Comment: @behemothus, простите, никакого вопроса, тем более в лоб, я не увидела, и спорить мне с Вами не о чем, я согласна, что "вопрос "что" предполагает любой вариант ответа, если заранее одушевленность не предполагается". С чем спорить-то? А Вы с чем в моём ответе спорить собирались? С этим:  "Вопрос что? может вбирать в себя представление о множестве предметов - и одушевлённых, и неодушевлённых"? А это не одно и то же? Или с тем, что привела значение слова "предмет"? Не поняла. Да и вообще не люблю спорить, да и некогда мне, простите, что не поддержала дискуссию, не увидела её смысла.

Comment: @Людмила *никакого вопроса, тем более в лоб, я не увидела* - я не хочу его повторять третий раз, но вынужден это сделать. Если вы опчять его не "заметите", то да, спорить будет не о чем.  Как вы считаете, в этом вопросе ***"Что просил князь у Хас-Булата взамен богатства? Жену, коня, раба, сына" необходимо уточнение "или кого?"***.

Comment: @behemothus, вопрос звучит в Вашем ответе, надеюсь, автору вопроса, а я здесь при чём?(Ко мнеотносилось только "Не хочу я спорить с Людмилой по поводу разбора каждого примера") Не собиралась и я  спорить. И вдруг:" Я вам каждый раз задаю вопрос в лоб - и каждый раз вы от него уходите".Если Вы считаете, что задали его мне, то отвечаю: Никакого уточнения не надо, и повторяю: потому что  "Вопрос что? может вбирать в себя представление о множестве предметов - и одушевлённых, и неодушевлённых".

Comment: А если где-то когда-то не ответила на Ваш вопрос, то извините, я просто не захожу в уже решённые вопросы повторно, если на почту не приходят вопросы лично мне, там всегда есть кому ответить, кроме меня, например, у Sharon ответы всегда избыточны.

Answer (score 1):

> Что изображено на гербе Москвы? (Георгий Победоносец с драконом).

Я бы посмотрела, что там в перечне вариантов ответа: если только перечень лиц святых, т.е. одушевлённых предметов, то более корректен был бы вопрос: Кто изображен на гербе Москвы? Если в перечне есть неодушевлённые предметы, например, рыцарский щит (он же тоже присутствует на гербе), то верен вариант с вопросительным словом что?

> Чем расплачиваются селениты за товары и услуги в произведении Сирано
> де Бержерака? Один из неверных вариантов "Детьми".

А в верных вариантах есть ответы с употреблением неодушевлённых предметов? Тогда лучше использовать **что?** Вопрос **что?** может вбирать в себя представление о множестве предметов - и одушевлённых, и неодушевлённых. Вопрос что? задаётся к предмету в отличие от действия или признака, а что такое предмет?

> ПРЕДМЕ́Т, -а, м.
>
> 1. Всякое конкретное, материальное явление, воспринимаемое органами чувств и мышлением как нечто существующее особо, Одушевленный предмет.
>    Неодушевленный предмет. □ *Встав с постели, Аркадий раскрыл окно — и
>    первый предмет, бросившийся ему в глаза, был Василий Иванович. Тургенев, Отцы и дети.*

Мы же можем спросить: *Что бросилось в глаза Аркадию?*

> Что такое "зеница ока"? Один из неверных вариантов "Близкий человек"

Вполне корректный вопрос: Что такое "зеница ока"? = Какой предмет мы называем "зеницей ока"?

> Что получает команда знатоков "Что? Где? Когда?" при правильном
> досрочном ответе? Один из неверных вариантов "Дополнительного игрока".

То же самое, вопрос **что?** вбирает в себя все возможные материальные явления, в том числе и одушевлённые. Считаю,что никакое расширение не требуется, всё понятно.

Comment: Да, в вопросе о селенитах варианты: воздухом, детьми, зубами, стихами (верный). В вариантах о гербе присутствуют как одушевленные, так и неодушевленные предметы.

Comment: Спасибо, это интересно. Мне внутренне кажется, что расширение не требуется, но до сих пор не удавалось найти какое-то правило/подтверждение.